# Exposing minikube ( running on docker ) IP

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, minikube

I have Minikube cluster running on docker ( windows 10 + WSL ) , This cluster running 3 simple applications , each of them has service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: firstapp
  labels:
    run: firstapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    run: firstapp
```

3 service for each app ( firstapp , secondapp ,thiredapp)
, now i have an Ingress for them , that is using the Minikube IP .

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: firstapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: firstapp
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: secondapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: secondapp
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: thiredapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: thiredapp
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I want to access this ingress with my web-Browser on my computer and I can't , if im connecting to the cluster with SHPOD for example and I curl the endpoint I get a response , but I don't want to curl for internet app in the cluster I want to access from my computer , what I need to do to accomplish that ?

[GIT](https://github.com/ITBeyder/NginxSites.git)

Answer (score 1):

First you have enalbe the **ingress-nginx** **controller** on the minikube

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Verify installation is working or not

```
kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
```

after that, you can apply the ingress changes and access ingress locally from the browser

as you are on local you might need add entry in /etc/host for ingress record

`firstapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io` will point the `IP` of the host or you can verify once using the command

```
kubectl get ingress
```

Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response , but I did not clearly understood ,
i run " kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx " and i see there is a pod running  , when i run " kubectl get ingress " i see this output : example-ingress   <none>   firstapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io,secondapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io,thiredapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io   192.168.49.2 , what do i need to do now to access the web apps from my browser?
becuse when i try to ping the host ( minikube ) i dont get response  , i run minikube ip -> receive 192.168.49.2 but i can not access it from web

Comment: did you got anything in address section ? `kubectl get ingress`

Comment: Im getting : 192.168.49.2

Comment: you can check this article there is steps : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/.

Comment: but i can not access this ip 192.168.49.2 trough my web browser

Comment: you have to add this entry into /etc/host

Comment: yes I followed this article but somehow it wont work for me

Comment: 192.168.49.2 firstapp.192.168.49.2.nip.io and same for other two

Comment: Did you checked your PODs up & running ?

Comment: but i should first be able to access from my browser to :192.168.49.2 right ?

Comment: yes, if ingress is up & running. check the ingress controller is & running, also your application pods

Comment: yes the pods are up and running , the IP 192.168.49.2 is for the minikube cluster , its from the docker that running it , i dont understand how i can access http://192.168.49.2/ is now working , my computer does not know how to communicate with this private IP

Comment: if it's working for you can update the status of question also, and if answer helpful feel free to upvote.

Comment: its not working , i can not access the ingress IP 192.168.49.2 trough the web browser

Comment: what's coming in output ?

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that on Windows/MacOS and Docker you won't reach directly minikube IP. You have to call first `minikube tunnel` and then you can use `http://localhost` and this is the DNS which you should use within minikube ingress. For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "myapp.127.0.0.1.nip.io"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myservice
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

And just use in browser: http://myapp.127.0.0.1.nip.io/

PS. It could be required admin permission to make a tunnel with ingress controller as it's running by default on 80 port which is restricted.